# how can I fill several files with data?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a range of directories from 2010 to 2017 and a sub-directory in them from 1 to 12. There is a file in each sub-directory, I need to add a line to each of these files.

This is part of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/
touch test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/file_{0..9}.txt
```

Comment: `for x in test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/file_{0..9}.txt; do echo 'someinfo' > "$x"; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "42" | tee test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/file_{0..9}.txt
```

Append to files:

```
echo "42" | tee -a test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/file_{0..9}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, it was created a range of directories from 2010 to 2017 and a range of sub-directories that goes from 1 to 12 in each directory. You also created nine files in each sub-directory at the end.

So, to append a new line in each of these files you should use the `echo` command to create the contents of your line and redirect it to the `tee` command to add it to all your files at once, as follows:

```
echo "new line" | tee -a test/201{0..7}/{1..12}/file_{0..9}.txt
```

That should be enough.